# Regex for huge string

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I have the below string:

```
"\n  - MyLibrary1 (= 0.10.0)\n  - AFNetworking (= 1.1.0)\n  - MyLibrary2 (= 3.0.0)\n  - Objective-C-HMTL-Parser (= 0.0.1)\n\n"
```

I want to create a JSON like this:

```
{
"MyLibrary1": "0.10.0",
"AFNetworking": "1.1.0",
"MyLibrary2": "3.0.0",
"Objective-C-HMTL-Parser": "0.0.1"
}
```

For which I need to separate "MyLibrary1" and "0.10.0" and similarly other data to create a string. I am working on a regex to separate data from the string.

I tried `/-(.*)/` and `/=(.*)/` but this returns me everything after `-` and `=`.

Is there a way to get the required data using single regex?  Also how do I let regex know that it needs to stop at `(` or `)`. I am using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test this and whenever I type `(` or `)` I get "You have an unmatched parenthesis."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex.

```
-\s*(\S+)\s*\(\s*=\s*(\S+)\s*\)
```

Your key match results will be in capturing group `#1` and the value match results will be in group `#2`

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/KEcLocKlDE)

Comment: I see this works in Rubular, but any idea why is it just retuning me the first data in ruby i.e. it returns me "- MyLibrary1 (= 0.10.0)"? Am I missing something here? All I did was I stored my string in a variable named dependencies and then I use the regex on it "dependencies[/-\s*(\S+)\s*(\s*=\s*(\S+))/]"

Comment: You need to print the match groups. Probably use scan as well

Comment: Yup scan helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work with your sample.

```
 # -\s*(.*?)\s*\(\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\)

 -
 \s* 
 ( .*? )        # (1)
 \s* 
 \(
 \s* 
 =
 \s* 
 ( .*? )        # (2)
 \s* 
 \)
```

Or, you could put in some mild validation. Note that the lazy quantifiers are used just
to trim whitespace.

```
 # -\s*([^()=]*?)\s*\(\s*=\s*([^()=-]*?)\s*\)

 -
 \s* 
 ( [^()=]*? )  # (1)
 \s* 
 \(
 \s* 
 =
 \s* 
 ( [^()=-]*? )  # (2)
 \s* 
 \)
```

Comment: Your solution is working on rubular, but any idea why is it just returning me just the first data when I use it in ruby? Do I need to add something while using it in ruby? I am doing dependencies.match(/-\s*(.*?)\s*\(\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\)/) where "dependencies" variable has the string in it.

Comment: In ruby it just returns me #<MatchData "- MyLibrary1 (= 0.10.0)" 1:"MyLibrary1" 2:"0.10.0">

Comment: Should just use a search function in global scope (global modifier). Also, what's returned that is of interest to you is in capture groups 1 and 2, not the whole match.

Comment: From your string its 1:"`MyLibrary1`" 2:"`0.10.0`"

Answer (score 0):

```
-\s{1}([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s+\(=\s+([0-9\.]+)\)
```

Will return matches:

$1 AFNetworking
$2 1.1.0

etc...

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/2jzwLi0gGH)